# Unwanted recv() fails WSAETIMEDOUT after shutdown on Windows

Tags: windows, sockets, winsock2

For some unknown reason, Windows seems to activate some kind of 120 second receive timeout, when I shutdown the sending side of a socket. Is there any way to avoid this?

This code demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace boost::asio::ip;

void server()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    tcp::acceptor server(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 2000));
    tcp::socket s(io_service);

    server.accept(s, ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "accept() failed: %s\n", ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }
    boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer("start\n", 6), ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "write() failed: %s\n", ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(130));
    boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer("end\n", 4), ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "write() failed: %s\n", ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argtv[])
{
    std::thread(server).detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));


    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed\n");
        return 2;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(2000);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "connect() failed\n");
        return 3;
    }

    if (shutdown(s, 1) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "shutdown() failed\n");

    for (;;)
    {
        char buffer[256];
        int n = recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            std::error_code ec(GetLastError(), std::system_category());
            fprintf(stderr, "recv failed: %s\n", ec.message().c_str());
            break;
        }
        if (!n)
            break;
        fwrite(buffer, 1, n, stdout);
    }

}
```

I expelct the program to first print `start` and after 130 seconds print `end` and terminate. But after 120 seconds, `recv()` fails:

```
start
recv failed: Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat.
```

I can use `setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO)` to reduce this unwanted timeout, but I did not manage to increase it or turn it off.

The program works fine on Linux (when removing `WSAStartup()` and replacing `GetLastError()` with `errno`).

It runs fine on Windows, too, if I don't shutdown the sending side of the socket. But I have to do this to signal the peer system that the request is complete. This demo does not have a request message, but my real system sends a variable-sized request message, so I have to shutdown the sender to let the server know it has received the entire request message.

The timeout does not hit when the server is sending data, but if there is a 120 second gap in the receive stream, `recv()`  fails with `WSAETIMEDOUT`. :-(

---

@Remy Lebeau: You seem to be on the right track to the cause of the problem. I added some system("netstat ...") statements and now I can see an additional  difference between windows and linux. Here is my current test program:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace boost::asio::ip;

void server()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    tcp::acceptor server(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 2000));
    tcp::socket s(io_service);

    server.accept(s, ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "accept() failed: %s\n", ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }
    boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer("start\n", 6), ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "write() failed: %s\n", ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(130));
    boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer("end\n", 4), ec);
    if (ec)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "write() failed: %s\n", ec.message().c_str());
        return;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argtv[])
{
    std::thread(server).detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));

#ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (err)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
#endif

    int s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed\n");
        return 2;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(2000);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "connect() failed\n");
        return 3;
    }

    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    if (getsockname(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getpeername() failed\n");
        return 3;
    }
    printf("Connected to server, my port=%u\n", ntohs(addr.sin_port));
    std::ostringstream ss;
#ifdef _WIN32
    ss << "netstat -tn | find \"" << ntohs(addr.sin_port) << "\"";
#else
    ss << "netstat -tn | grep \"" << ntohs(addr.sin_port) << "\"";
#endif
    system(ss.str().c_str());

    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    if (shutdown(s, 1) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "shutdown() failed\n");
    printf("shutdown\n");
    system(ss.str().c_str());

    for (;;)
    {
        char buffer[256];
        int n = recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (n < 0)
        {
#ifdef _WIN32
            auto error = WSAGetLastError();
#else
            auto error = errno;
#endif
            std::error_code ec(error, std::system_category());
            fprintf(stderr, "recv failed, n=%d: %s\n", n, ec.message().c_str());
            break;
        }
        if (!n)
            break;
        fwrite(buffer, 1, n, stdout);
    }
    printf("recv loop terminated after %lu s\n", (unsigned long)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()-start).count());
    system(ss.str().c_str());
    printf("finished\n" );

}
```

On Windows, I get this output:

```
Connected to server, my port=50807
  TCP    127.0.0.1:2000         127.0.0.1:50807        HERGESTELLT     InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50807        127.0.0.1:2000         HERGESTELLT     InHost
shutdown
  TCP    127.0.0.1:2000         127.0.0.1:50807        SCHLIESSEN_WARTEN    InHost
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50807        127.0.0.1:2000         FIN_WARTEN_2    InHost
start
recv failed, n=-1: Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat.

recv loop terminated after 120 s
finished
```

on linux it looks this different, the server socket is still listed:

```
Connected to server, my port=52864
tcp        6      0 127.0.0.1:52864         127.0.0.1:2000          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2000          127.0.0.1:52864         ESTABLISHED
shutdown
tcp        6      0 127.0.0.1:52864         127.0.0.1:2000          FIN_WAIT2
tcp        1      0 127.0.0.1:2000          127.0.0.1:52864         CLOSE_WAIT
start
end
recv loop terminated after 129 s
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52864         127.0.0.1:2000          TIME_WAIT
finished
```

Comment: If the sender actually closes the sending end of the socket, ie with `shutdown(SD_SEND)`, then a `FIN` packet is sent to the receiver, and a pending `recv()` will return immediately with a return value of 0. There is no timeout on a shutdown. So whatever your timeout issue is, it is related to something else. But you have not shown your receive code.

Comment: "*I have to [shutdown the socket] to signal the peer system, that the request is complete*" - no, you don't. That is an indication of a bad protocol design. "*my real systems sends a variable sized request message, so I have to shutdown the sender to let the server know, it has received the entire request message*" - then you should be sending a fixed header first to indicate the size of the variable sized data. That way, the receiver can read the header first and know exactly how many more bytes to read and then stop. DO NOT shutdown a socket just to indicate the end of a message.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: My code sample contains both, a server (using boost asio) and a client (using the native windows API). The client connects to the server on the loopback address.

Comment: @RemyLebeau:  In fact, I did exactly what you suggested and my program works fine now, but the question still remains, why recv() fails on windows 120s after shutting down the transmitting direction of the socket and wat can be done to avoid this timeout.

Comment: in 20+ years of socket programming, I have never experienced the kind of shutdown timeout you have described. But then, I've also never encountered a real world system that doesn't respond to socket closures in a more timely manner than what you are testing with. 120 seconds is 2*MSL, the same timeout that a socket stays in the `TIME_WAIT` state before being released. An OS can decide whether to stay in a `FIN_WAIT...` state forever or not when waiting for a `FIN` to arrive after sending a `FIN`.

Comment: My servers job is executing programs. The idea was to open a TCP connection server, send the program, the server executes the program and returns the output on the TCP stream. 

The program controls some hardware connected to the server and program execution may last several minutes. The program can be generated by code running on the client, so the length of the program is not known in advance. So I though of shutting down the TX side on the client to generate EOF at the server as terminaton. I changed to using chunked transfer encoding.